# In / Out Update Attendance System SQL Yii2

Tags: php, sql-server, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, time-and-attendance

I have this cases if Button "In" clicked,it will create a new record for attendance.and if Button "Out" clicked,it will update the record created from the new record before.
for cases like this,it should be done on SQL using query,or on Yii itself ?
what i've tried so far,i can create new record for "In" Button.but when i clicked "Out" Button,the record was not update,it creating a new record with Null In Time.
here is the design of table

```
id   empid    date       in     out   status   desc
1     20    2016-11-01  08:00           1       In
```

and this is the design of the form
[image]

EDIT :
This is my controller for "In" Button

```
public function actionIn()
{
   // $session->open();
   // $

    $model = new AttDetail();
    $idAbsen = Att::find()->where(['empID'=>Yii::$app->user->id])->one();
    $db = Yii::$app->getDb();
    $command = $db->createCommand('
        SELECT group_shift.In FROM group_shift JOIN att on group_shift.Id = att.IdGs WHERE att.empId = 1
    ');
    $In = $command->queryOne();      

    if ( $model->load( Yii::$app->request->post() ) && $model->save() ) 
    {
      return $this->redirect(['index', 'id' => $model->Id]);
    }
    else 
    {
        return $this->render('in', [
            'model' => $model,
            'in' => $in,
            'in' => $idAtt
        ]);
    }
}
```

and this is my Index

```
'toolbar'=> [
         ['content'=>   Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> In', ['in'],['class'=>'btn btn-success']),

    ],
    ],
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'Id',
        'IdAtt',
        'Date',
        'In',
        'Out',

        ['class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
        'template' =>  Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Out', ['out'],['class'=>'btn btn-success']),
          'dropdown'=>false,
          'dropdownOptions'=>['class'=>'pull-right'],
```

i'm open to all suggestion about how this is could done.Thank You

Comment: update your question and show your view and controller/action retated code

Comment: i have edited my post,but i didnt use any view on this pagel,i used an Index only @scaisEdge

Comment: index.php  in views/your-model/index.php  is a view ..

Comment: oohh,that is the index code on my model's view i provided @scaisEdge

Answer (score 0):

Your template should be  (assuming that your model id is `empid`)

```
'template' =>  Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Out', 
    Url::to(['your-controller/out', 'empid=> $model->empid]),['class'=>'btn btn-success']),
```

but there isn't code for action out

you should add a proper (update ) code for actionOut

somethings like this for update (this is  just a suggestion )

```
public function actionOn($empid)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($empid);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
       ......
       // your redirec..
    } else {
        return $this->render('your_view', [
            ....
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Then if you don't assign a prope action to you link how do you think to manage the update ?  .. .. i have update the answer ..

Comment: i already made that,but it update the whole record,and In can be inputted to.and i already tried put $model->isNewRecord to the form,but it wont run

Comment: @BaktiWijaya   your first question was for "but when i clicked "Out" Button,the record was not update,it creating a new record with Null In Time."  then if the record is update with out action the problem in your questo should be solved .. seems that you are changing the term of you question  and i can't understand  your prolem e so i can't help you .. you should deal with a problem at a time with a question at a time